# HTMLUnit login to school email using java eclipse with https://

Tags: java, webclient, htmlunit

I am working on creating an application where I can pull the information from my schools website, like my class schedule and assignments, so that I don't have to login every time I want to get this info. Simple.

Here is my main class that I am using to call the website to get it.

```
public class HttpRequestsExample {

final private static String email = "email";
final private static String password = "password";
static HtmlPage secondPage;

public static WebClient tremorLogin(WebClient webClient) throws Exception {

    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);

    HtmlPage currentPage = webClient.getPage("school login site");

    final HtmlForm form = currentPage.getFormByName("loginf");

    final HtmlTextInput textFieldName = form.getInputByName("j_username");
    final HtmlPasswordInput textFieldPass = form.getInputByName("j_password");
    textFieldName.setValueAttribute(email);
    textFieldPass.setValueAttribute(password);
    final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByValue("  Login  ");
    secondPage = button.click();

    return webClient;

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient = tremorLogin(webClient);

    String pageSource = secondPage.asXml();

    System.out.println(pageSource);
}
}
```

Here is the form that I am trying to get to but it is saying that the "loginf" is non existent.

```
<form name="loginf" action="/idp/Authn/UserPassword" method="post" autocomplete="off">

                <td>
                &nbsp;<input name="j_username" type="text" tabindex="1" style="width:150px" autocapitalize="off">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                <b>Password:</b></td>
                <td>
                &nbsp;<input name="j_password" type="password" tabindex="2" style="width:150px">
                </td>
            </tr>

            </tbody></table>
            </form>
```

Here is the error that I get

```
Exception in thread "main" com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[form] attributeName=[name] attributeValue=[loginf]
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.getFormByName(HtmlPage.java:638)
at HttpRequestsExample.tremorLogin(HttpRequestsExample.java:34)
at HttpRequestsExample.main(HttpRequestsExample.java:51)
```

Comment: Please use latest version, or [build](https://ci.canoo.com/teamcity/viewLog.html?buildTypeId=HtmlUnit_FastBuild&buildId=lastSuccessful&tab=artifacts), `setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(true)`, and print `currentPage.asXml()` to see what HtmlUnit sees. Otherwise, please post your URL with credentials if possible

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead :

```
HtmlPage currentPage = webClient.getPage("school login site");
HtmlTextInput textField2 = (HtmlTextInput) currentPage.getElementByName("j_username");
textField2.setValueAttribute(email);
HtmlTextInput textField3 = (HtmlTextInput) currentPage.getElementByName("j_password");
textField3.setValueAttribute(password);
```